# table with one header and data from Array inside a Map with thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I want to create a table that its data is a Map< String, List < Object> >.

So the table has one header that and the rows should have the exact data.

- Map.key
- Object.item1
- Object.item2
- Object.item3

So since it is a List of Object i want one row for every Object of the List and the Map.key to be repeated.

So i need to iterate through keys like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each= "result : ${myMap}">
            <td th:text="${result.key}"></td>
            <td><table>
                <tr th:each="obj: ${result.value}">
                    <td th:text="${not #lists.isEmpty(obj.errorList)}?'Error':'Warning'"></td>
                    <td th:text="${obj.flag}==true?'YES':'NO'"></td>
                    <td th:text="${not #lists.isEmpty(obj.errorList)}?${obj.warningList}:${obj.errorList}"></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but this solution places a table in a table. I want to use one header and iterate the lists and place the variables in the main table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a structure like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each= "result : ${myMap}">
            <tr th:each="obj: ${result.value}">
                <td th:text="${result.key}" />
                <td th:text="${not #lists.isEmpty(obj.errorList)}?'Error':'Warning'" />
                <td th:text="${obj.flag}==true?'YES':'NO'" />
                <td th:text="${not #lists.isEmpty(obj.errorList)}?${obj.warningList}:${obj.errorList}" />
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you also explain to me what the th:block do. i have read the thymeleaf manual but i did not understood it

Comment: The main purpose of `<th:block />` is to let you use Thymeleaf attributes like `th:each` and `th:if` without creating an HTML tag.  In your case, you need to loop over two different Lists, but you don't want to create a table row for each Map.key (only for the values), so you use a `<th:block />` on the outer loop.

Comment: i want to ask also something. When i get a Map with list.size >1 then this solution gives only the first item of the List not all. Is this possible or not?